Qstopmotion cannot find ffmpeg encoder on my computer, allthough it is installed
I just started working with Qstopmotion on an Ubuntu system and I am trying to export my video using the ffmpeg encoder. Qstopmotion keeps throwing the error message:
The selected encoder is not installed on your computer.
Install the encoder or select another one!

However, ffmpeg is installed on my computer, if I type in $ ffmpeg --version in the terminal I get version
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers 

I have already played with the preferences, trying to change the output format from mp4 to avi but nothing seems to help. Does someone know what else I can try?
